# How to make user input a password field access query?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have made an access query to show some client records, the where condition is basically enter the name and a password, i achieve that by using :

```
WHERE (((Contractor_Appointments.Consultant) Like [Enter Consultant's Name here] & "*") AND ((Contractor_Appointments.Lead_Status) Not Like "Satisfactory") AND ((Consultants.Passwords)=[Enter Password]))
```

But the things is i want it to treat the password field as a password and put * instead of character when i am typing . Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new form.  Add a text box control.  On the property sheet for the text box, select the Other tab and change the Name property to txtPassword.  Then, on the Data tab, use Password as the Input Mask property.  Save the form as frmPassword.

```
WHERE
    (((Contractor_Appointments.Consultant) Like [Consultant's Name] & "*")
    AND ((Contractor_Appointments.Lead_Status) <> "Satisfactory")
    AND ((Consultants.Passwords)=[Forms]![frmPassword]![txtPassword]))
```

Then, open frmPassword in Form View, type in your password and open the query.

If that outline is close to what you want, it can be refined further.  But first see if this suggestion is close.

Answer (score 0):

This looks fairly imaginary in terms of security. However, you can use a form to get the password. At least that way you can do some checking before running it into your database.

Comment: I get the password and it is checked , that's not the issue here .The question is can i make the text field a password field .Thank you

Comment: Yes, if you use a form to supply the password and refer to the form in your where statement.

Comment: I am taking it or matching it directly from the table , so can i do that way? Thank you

Comment: Create a form with controls for the user to fill in. Refer to the controls in your query: `SELECT Stuff FROM MyTable WHERE Something=Forms!MyForm!MyTextbox`